# Add content to /wp-admin/plugin-install.php admin screens

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin

I would like to add some external content to the plugin information displayed on the `/wp-admin/plugin-install.php` admin screens.

`/wp-admin/plugin-install.php` calls the following:

```
$wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Plugin_Install_List_Table');
```

And if I hack this core file as a test, I can add the content, I want, OK.

However as a new WP developer I am really struggling to see how I can add this content via a plugin.

`class WP_Plugin_Install_List_Table` extends `WP_List_Table` so I don't think I can extend this any further.

Is there a way to add content via a plugin to these screens?

Comment: You can extend an already extended class. What content do you want to add and where?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I would like to add a couple of rows of text pulled from the external site below each plugins Description in the /wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=new or wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=popular screens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without extending the class, what can be done is adding a Custom Action Link:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_install_action_links', 'action_links_wpse_119218', 10, 2 );

function action_links_wpse_119218( $links, $plugin )
{
    if( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) )
    {
        switch( $_GET['tab'] )
        {
            case 'featured':                                         
                $links['my-action'] = "Tested up to <a href='#'>{$plugin['tested']}</a>";
            break;                                                   
            case 'popular':                                          
                $links['my-action'] = "Requires <a href='#'>{$plugin['requires']}</a>";
            break;                                                   
            case 'new':                                              
                $links['my-action'] = "Slug <a href='#'>{$plugin['slug']}</a>";
            break;                                                   
        }
    }
    return $links;
}
```

[image]

And then, you can proceed to move the element around with jQuery:

```
$('.move-me').each(function(){ /* your_magic(); */ });
```

---

That custom link, *My view*, is added with:

```
add_filter( 'views_plugin-install', 'views_wpse_119218' );

function views_wpse_119218( $views ){
    $views['my-view'] = '<a href="#">My view</a>';
    return $views;
}
```

This would be used to create your own custom screen/table with `add_action( 'load-plugin-install.php', 'callback' )`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is really helpful, it does however trigger a 'Warning call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'callback()' was given on line 406 in file /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php' Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Comment: I've updated the answer with PHP5.2 compatible code.

Comment: Thanks again, you have been really helpful. The solution works very well